MAPBOX in jetpack compose
I'm trying to install MAPBOX on my Android Kotlin Compose project, but I'm getting an error in my terminal. I have followed the documentation https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/ but still nothing...
@OptIn(MapboxExperimental::class)
@Composable
fun MapBoxScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    innerPadding: PaddingValues,
    isDarkTheme: Boolean,
    onThemeChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
            .background(MaterialTheme.corim.background)
    ) {
        MapboxMap(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            mapViewportState = MapViewportState().apply {
                setCameraOptions {
                    zoom(2.0)
                    center(Point.fromLngLat(-98.0, 39.5))
                    pitch(0.0)
                    bearing(0.0)
                }
            },
        )
    }
}

display the map in my project
enter image description here

Can You provide an error message?
